# Unable to push to GitHub repository - "remote: invalid credentials" error

Tags: github, credentials

I've been encountering an issue when trying to push my local repository to a remote GitHub repository. Each time I try, I receive an error message stating "remote: invalid credentials" and "fatal: Authentication failed."

Here's what I have tried so far
I made sure to use the correct GitHub account and token.
I checked that the remote URL of the repository is correct.
I created a new personal access token.
But I am still unable to push my changes to the remote repository as I get the same error.

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to resolve this issue ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Write the full error what you are seeing, if you make the changes in your own repo

Comment: Here is the full error message
"remote: invalid credentials
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Dany128/OneShotTyper.git/'
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i m right, then you are trying to push your commit to this repo `github.com/Dany128/OneShotTyper.git`, which is doesn't exist. So, I say that error is very genuine. If it is not the case, then you need to change your remote with valid repo. If your repo is not existed.

```
git remote set-url origin <new-repository-url>

git remote add origin <new-repository-url>

git push -u origin main
```

It's not solving your error, then you can try using SSH. To do this, you will need to generate a new SSH key and add it to your GitHub account. GitHub has a helpful guide on how to do this: [**GitHub ssh**](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

in the end, if any solving is not working for you, then there is only one way to connect with GitHub support: [**GitHub support**](https://support.github.com/request)

Comment: The repo is private, I'll try using ssh at this point. Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the HTTPS URL, and Git fails using the correct authentication, it is possible the wrong credentials are cached (and used).

Check if you have a git credential helper defined:

```bash
git config --global credential.helper
xxx
```

Then use that value 'xxx' in a Git bash session to check :

```bash
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx get
```

If you see a different user, or the right user but with a different password or token, set the right value with:

```bash
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=yourAccount" | git credential-xxx store yourToken
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
I see my token based URL in the credentials, I deleted the credentials and still have the same error 
remote: invalid credentials
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Dany128/OneShotTyper.git/'

Comment: @DanyJamous Try the `get` command again, to see if there are any other credentials attached to `github.com`. If not, the next clone will trigger a popup, where you can enter your GitHub account name and your PAT (Personal Access Token): use a token, not your account password.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that when you created the token, you did not specify the allowed repository access tokens.

I previously encountered the same problem and managed to solve it by recreating a new token and specifying read and write access.